# How to improve the ugly layout in R shiny

Tags: r, button, shiny, layout

I want to display a list of buttons using the package `shiny` in R in a way similar to the java gridLayout:

[Desired layout](https://i.imgur.com/XHce1It.jpeg)

After some trial and error I could produce [this result](https://i.imgur.com/4o7CyYt.png). Unfortunately the buttons are not square and there is some space between rows, which I would like to avoid.

Could you suggest how to improve this layout?

My R code follows below:

```
library(shiny)

buttons <- list()

for (r in 1:3){
  for (c in 1:4){
    index <- c + r * 4 - 4
    
    buttons[[index]] <- absolutePanel(
      style='background-color:skyblue;',
      actionButton(style='background-color:#FFFFA0;',
                    paste0("but", as.character(index)),
                    index, width = 60, height = 60),
      top = 60 * r , left = 60 * c, width = 60, height = 60)
  }
}

# user interface
ui <- fixedPage(absolutePanel(buttons))

# server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do exactly what you want is using `css`. To this, I added a class to the button and the add CSS code to achieve the desired output.

```
library(shiny)

buttons <- list()

for (r in 1:3){
  for (c in 1:4){
    index <- c + r * 4 - 4
    
    buttons[[index]] <- absolutePanel(
      style='background-color:skyblue;',
      actionButton(class="square-button",
                   paste0("but", as.character(index)),
                   index, width = 80, height = 0),
      top = 80 * r , left = 80 * c, width = 80, height = 0)
  }
}

# user interface
ui <- fixedPage(
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue&display=swap"),
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      ".square-button {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width: 60px;
          height: 80px;
          line-height: 60px;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 25px;
          font-weight: bold;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px; 
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #969CA3;
          border-radius: 0px;
          background-color: skyblue;
          background-image: linear-gradient(white, #BFD4E9);
          font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive; /* Apply comic font */
        }")),
  absolutePanel(buttons))

# server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great job on reconstructing exactly the java style! I will see if I could remove some features to have a less verbose code.

Answer (score 2):

With a table:

```r
library(shiny)

nrows <- 3
ncols <- 4
rows <- vector("list", length = nrows)
for(r in 1:nrows){
  buttons <- lapply(1:ncols, function(c) {
    index <- c + 4*r - 4
    tags$td(
      actionButton(style='background-color: #FFFFA0; height: 60px;',
                   paste0("but", as.character(index)),
                   index, width = 60)
    )
  })
  rows[[r]] <- do.call(tags$tr, buttons)
}
body <- do.call(tags$tbody, rows)
tbl <- tags$table(body)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tbl
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image]